# how to open pdf in webview for android in xamarin.forms?

Tags: pdf, webview, xamarin.forms

I am creating an android app in xamarin.forms. I am getting an url for pdf in the app. First I have to download the pdf and save it locally. Then I have to show that downloaded pdf in webview. But I am getting white screen in webview. Its not showing the pdf. But if I open any url then it shows in webview.
Anyone know how I can do this?
Following is my code that I am using for opening the pdf:
  XAML:

```
<WebView x:Name="browser" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

C#:

```
 browser.Source = pdfFile;
```

Comment: did you get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The WebViewer cannot display pdf-files natively on Android or Windows Phone, it only works on iOS. In order for this to work you need to use a javascript library.

You can find all necessary infos including tutorials on how to display pdf within WebView for all Platforms on here: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/

Answer (score 0):

(For Android) I have create a binding-library for PDFView base on JoanZapata's work.

You can download sourcecode from github.(There is sample project in it)
https://github.com/pranart/Xamarin.DroidPdfView.Binding.Library

Answer (score 0):

the way to do that in xamarin android is 
see the code below:

```
WebView webview = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
    urlPdf = ("example of url");
    WebSettings settings = webview.Settings;
    settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    webview.LoadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + urlPdf);
```

Comment: We wanted for Xamarin.Forms